# Issue with dropdown boxes resetting to empty selection on change

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue with dropdown boxes using ng-model and changing the index of the dropdown while being still able to use the dropdown.

For instance, I can change the index of the drop down using this code (http://jsfiddle.net/Q5hd6/357/). However, when I change the index it defaults back to an empty selection then refuses to let me select anything else.

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="RecievedSelect" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in RecievedOptions"></select>
<button ng-click="ChangeIndex()">Change index</button>
```

JS:

```
    $scope.RecievedOptions  = [
                              {id : 0, name: "No"}, 
                              {id : 1, name: "Yes"} 
                            ];

    $scope.ChangeIndex = function()
  {
        $scope.RecievedSelect = $scope.RecievedOptions[0];
  }
```

But if I remove `track by item.id` I'm able to change the indexes manually, but can no longer change them with the button (http://jsfiddle.net/Q5hd6/358/).

Basically, I would like to do both, but I am sort of lost on where to go next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `$scope.RecievedSelect = $scope.RecievedOptions[0].id;` because the select element's model contains the value of the selected option.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.RecievedOptions  = [
                             {id : 0, name: "No"}, 
                             {id : 1, name: "Yes"}
                            ];                          
  $scope.ChangeIndex = function() {
      $scope.RecievedSelect = $scope.RecievedOptions[0].id;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<select ng-model="RecievedSelect" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in RecievedOptions"></select>
<button ng-click="ChangeIndex()">Change index</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense now. I didn't consider that I was overwriting the selected bool. Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

This works in the case of the ng-options because it does not create a new scope as stated in [AngularJs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) but the rest of my words is valid for ng-model directive and any directive that creates a new scope:(in the case of ng-repeat for every item in the array it will create a new child scope, you can read about this mechanism [Understand the concept of scopes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) ) but it is always a good pattern to follow.

And if you don't pass through an object then the child scope will create its own value here the `ReceivedSelect` this is a JavaScript behaviour that is why you have to change it to an attribue of an object like `sct.ReceivedSelect`.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

<select ng-model="sct.RecievedSelect" ng-options="item as item.name for item in RecievedOptions track by item.id"></select>
<button ng-click="ChangeIndex()">Change index</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.RecievedOptions  = [
                              {id : 0, name: "No"}, 
                              {id : 1, name: "Yes"} 
                            ];
    $scope.sct = {RecievedSelect : $scope.RecievedOptions[0]};                                
    $scope.ChangeIndex = function() {
     $scope.sct.RecievedSelect = $scope.RecievedOptions[0];
    }
});
```

Take a look on this JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q5hd6/367/